# Ошибка в приложении android при работе

Tags: java, android

В примитивном, тестовом приложении студия выдает ошибку. Ошибка на физическом устройстве. В студии следующий текст:

> On devices with API level below 21, a full build is required if the
> app is not running

На всякий случай прикладываю код.
Код из `activity_main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
       android:text="@string/text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/button"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
       android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код из `MainActivity.java` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                text.setText("Нажата кнопка");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: `findViewById` нужно делать после `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        text.setText("Нажата кнопка");
    }
});

}
}
```

Comment: Все сделал как показали. Приложение запускается но после нажатия на кнопку оно вылетает. Что теперь делать ?

Comment: слудующая ошибка в точ что в активити ты используеш 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
вместо setContentView(R.layout.main); У тебя активность ничего не знает про файл разметки mail

Comment: ошибка еще повторилась?

Comment: Вместо activity_main оставить main ? Но в папке layout нет такого файла.

Comment: У тебя в разметке `android:id="@+id/textView"`. А ищешь `findViewById(R.id.text);`